# Special path in nautilus

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

There are some special "path" in nautilus that do not correspond to any location on the drive.

So far, I know of `network:///` , `favorites:///` , `recent:///` and `admin:///`

How are these called, and what are all of them?

Comment: Please read this info https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Under ubuntu 20. Same seen in ubuntu 18, ubuntu 22, and mint 21. Edited tags

Comment: Ubuntu 18. 20 and 22 would be versions of Ubuntu Core that is the only version of Ubuntu using single digit version. Mint is not supported on this site at all.

Comment: I don't really get why the question is closed, because I don't see any detail I could add... Anyway I found the answer on another source. Those are gvfs names listed here : https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/schemes